# What does the following mean in git log --oneline?

Tags: git

I have forked the repos of https://github.com/scm-ninja/starter-web  (doing udemy course on git branching and merging) and doing the git log --oneline command gives me the following:

```
git log --oneline
e297774 (HEAD -> master) Adding purpose of project
a846fdb Adding project description
e9c0f5f (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Adding new section: Deployment
b2133eb Adding README2.md
4beb7f0 Merge pull request #6 from jasongtaylor/feature-readme
e73f914 Adding Purpose section to README
34f563b Adding README file
5c05047 Copying files from initializr project zip file and then creating simple.html as basis for super simple pages
```

According to atlassian docs, the top commit's (HEAD -> master) means this commit is currently checked out, makes sense.

So I'm wondering, why does the 3rd commit from top (3rd last) have this? I've only done a simple edit, add and push to origin. A new file (README2.md) was added in the previous commit.

> (origin/master, origin/HEAD)

help appreciated,
g

Comment: Well where is the problem? Thats where your `origin/master` is pointing to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
e297774 (HEAD -> master) Adding purpose of project
```

That's the head (the topmost commit) of your local master branch. It is ahead of remote master branch by two commits according to the output of git log:

```
e297774 (HEAD -> master) Adding purpose of project
a846fdb Adding project description
e9c0f5f (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Adding new section: Deployment
```

It means that remote master's HEAD is at e9c0f5f whereas your local master's HEAD is already at e297774 (so you really added a couple of commits on top of e9c0f5f, but you currently have them only locally).

Seems like you haven't really pushed your changes to the remote.
You could review your recent actions by issuing

```
history | grep git
```

To push your changes to the remote you could issue

```
git push origin master
```